# Google Maps KML text as marker

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, jak

After reviewing the documentation for KML it seems like the only option to display text on a map is to use the screenoverlay. However that does not meet my requirement. Is is possible to display text, as a marker. This text will be dynamic and driven by a report so having static images does not meet the requirement. In google api v3 I have used markers with no icon to display text, is there something similar in kml?